# App crashes when implementing Action Bar support v7 library for android 2.3 and above

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

I have successfully created an app in Eclipse and it works for android 4.0 and above. Now I want to make it compatible also for android 2.3 and above. In my app I have used action bar, so I have added the android-support-v7-appcompat library project in my workset in my workspace. After following the http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html instructions, now I have 'android-support--v7-appcompat.jar' and 'android-support-v4.jar'under my projects Android Private Libraries section. Also I have the jar files under libs folder of my project.

In my Main Activity, I have imported:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
```

In AndroidManifest.xml file, I have declared:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" 

    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

Also, for different activities, declared as:

```
 <activity android:
                 android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

Previously my AndroidManifest.xml was like this:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" 

        android:theme="@style/<theme>"
```

and the styles.xml under res>values folder was like this:

```
    <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
       -->
       <style name="<base>" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
        </style>

        <!-- Application theme. -->
       <style name="<theme>" parent="<base>">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go      here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

used

```
  <style name="<base>" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
            <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
        </style>
```

in values-v11 folder and

```
<style name="<base>" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
        </style>
```

in values-v14 folder.

I have now included all the styles_base.xml and themes_base.xml files from the library project to my project. Also changed styles.xml file by replacing Theme with .

Every time I run the app, I face crashing, now even for 4.0 and later android versions. The message:

```
 java.main.NoClassDefFounderError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the compatibility libraries are checked in Project Properties -> Java Build Path --> Order and Export section like below:

[image]

Otherwise they will not be included in the generated APK.

**Edit:**

I think you should start over with this as you really shouldn't adding these XMLs from the support lib to your own project.

1. Remove all the XMLs and jars from support lib
2. Rebuild a new Android Library Project per the link you gave (follow the "Adding libraries with resources" instruction)
3. Add the Android Library Project to your project
4. Clean and rebuild project

Comment: I have checked Project Properties -> Java Build Path --> Order and Export section. both android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files are there. But each jar file is twice there. One showing location as my project's libs and another as the location where I downloaded the library project. One more thing, none of these jar files are checked, only Android Dependencies is checked. Do I need to make any change here.

Comment: I am surprised there's no error for having 2 instances of the same lib. You should try: 1. remove duplicate so only one instance exist; 2. check both of them; 3. clean and run the project

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just to make sure before removing jar files, in my project, I have these jar files under Android Private Libraries section and also I have the jar files under libs folder of my project. Which one should I delete? Also, do I need to uncheck Android Dependencies in Project Properties -> Java Build Path --> Order and Export section?

Comment: Also, want to add one more issue. I was trying on Styles.xml is this way:  <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    
        <item name = "actionBarStyle">
            @style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar
            </item>
    </style>

</resources> Getting error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried yours and some other solutions, it's working fine now!